# No space left on device after copying lots of files (but the disk is only half used)

Tags: 18.04, server, disk-usage, format

## Context

I have to copy on a [Ubuntu 18.04 server](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) roughly ~5'000'000  of small files which are cartographic tiles for a web application.

They are currently stored in a folder on an other machine with an XXL hard drive disk (1 TB). The total *weight* of this folder is a little less than 30 GB.

The destination folder on the server is a disk which have a 50 GB free space in a single ext4 partition. It should be OK.

## Error

While copying the file using [`scp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/scp.1.html), I end up with many of the following errors (they massively pop after having copied 3'271'897 files, maybe this number is important?):

```
(...)
scp: /media/data/tiles/16/69654: No space left on device
(...)
```

If I check for free space on the device, it shows:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
(...)
/dev/sdb1        49G   19G   28G  41% /media/data
```

So why the `"No space left on device"` message then ?

I have the feeling that the number of files is too large, regardless of the disk space, or something like that and that I miss an important concept...

And that it could maybe be possible to get rid of that message by "preparing" correctly the partition itself at some lower level (using `parted` for example).

Maybe [`ext4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) is not suited for holding lots of small files?

## Question

What do I need to be aware of to properly set up my 50 GB disk to effectively host 5'000'000 files (which should also have nice performances while serving them through a web application after)?

## Update

After Soren A's comment:

```
$ df -hi
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
(...)
/dev/sdb1        3.2M  3.2M     0  100% /media/data
```

Comment: Every time you have a file it uses an inode, many small files uses many inodes. Can you please update the question with the output from `df -hi` ?

Comment: This one sounds like it's actually filling the disk, indeed... I was missing the inode concept, obviously, I will study it a little...

Comment: One thing to look at is the `usage_type` option when formatting.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4